# how to remove https://rmut-glo.onstatedig from computer

Tags: https

how can I remove `https://rmut-glo.onstatedig` from my computer as it keeps slowing computer down and causing an infected pop up to display

Comment: Just dont open it. Check startup page in your browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)